# How do I display different view controllers in a uiview depending on selection through a tableview (Please see the image in description)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I want to create an ios app, using objectiveC, which has a products list view. I am looking to create a filter screen for this list, which has a tableview and another view which displays different custom viewcontrollers depending on the row selected in the first tableview. I am uploading a screenshot of a similar screen from a popular ecommerce app.

[image]

Can you please help me on how to handle the part where I will have to display different viewcontrollers in the uiview. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have very few custom viewcontrollers to shuffle, use [container view](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1)

Comment: What if I have to shuffle between a larger number of viewcontrollers.. around 20?

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollView for this it is easy to achieve your requirements:)

```
scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        scrollView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
        scrollView.delegate=self;
        scrollView.bounces=NO;
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.scrollsToTop=NO;
        scrollView.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(2*scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height - 60);

        collectionantZ *homeScreen =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yyy"];
        Antzclubtableview *antzClub =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xxx"];

        tableView1.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,19,scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
        tableView2.view.frame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,19,scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        [scrollView addSubview:tableView1.view];
        [scrollView addSubview:tableView2.view];


        [self addChildViewController:tableView1];
        [self addChildViewController:tableView2];
```

## in button Action do this:

```
- (IBAction)tableView1:(id)sender {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0.) animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)tableView2:(id)sender {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1 *scrollView.frame.size.width,0.) animated:YES];
}
```

if you have multiple view controller just adjust this code as per your need